# If $F(x)=\frac{x^4-3}{x^4+1}$ is a primitive of $f(x)$ find $\int_{0}^{1} xf(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

If $F(x)=\frac{x^4-3}{x^4+1}$ is a primitive of $f(x)$ find $\int_{0}^{1} xf(x) dx$

I literally have no idea how to integrate this.

I tried integrating by parts (and finding the derivative of $F(x)$) but I end up getting a even worse integral...

The correct answer apparently is $-3$.

Comment: Please check the statement of your exercise. The correct result is not $-3$!

Comment: Since $f(x)=F'(x)=\frac{16x^3}{x^4+1}$, there's no way that the integral is $-3$, because you're doing $\int_0^1\frac{16x^4}{x^4+1}\,dx$.

Comment: @parishilton egreg is right! Something is wrong here. Please check!!

Comment: Yep! Clearly it's not $-3$ but my solution says it's... I'm getting something very far away from -3. I'll try to ask my teacher about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Integrating by parts we have

$$\int_{0}^{1} xf(x) dx=[xF(x)]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1} F(x) dx$$

Comment: It should be $\int xf(x) dx=[xF(x)]_0^1-\int_{0}^{1} F(x) dx$.

Comment: @egreg Ah ok that's indeed what I wrote up there but not in the answer! I fix that :)

Comment: Thank you to everyone!!

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks a lot! I was sleeping at all :)

Comment: @parishilton You are welcome and sorry for the typo in the last part! I had in mind something but I wrote something different! Bye

Comment: @gimusi it's ok!! I understood the idea anyway :-)